# TypeError: i.chart is undefined

Tags: highcharts, undefined

When I am loading my chart I get this error **TypeError: i.chart is undefined**
What is this issue?
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo, on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Actually I don't know when the error occurs but i see that some times on reloading the chart.

Comment: Unfortunately without demo and scenario, we are not able to replicate this issue.